# Fails to correctly print a diamond shape of a specific height in Scala

Tags: scala

I tried writing a program in Scala where the height is given and the diamond should be printed within the given height, which means its top to bottom should be equal to the height as follows-

height 7

```
                           #
                          ###
                         #####
                        #######
                         #####
                          ###
                           #
```

height 4

```
             #
            ###
            ###
             #
```

My output looks like this when I'm trying to print:

```
           height = 4





             #  ###  ###  #
            Process finished with exit code 0
```

It'd be much appreciated if someone can give me a hint why the below code doesn't print the desired output:

```
object Exercises {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 print(diamondString(4))

def diamondString(height : Int) : String = {
  var diamond : String = ""
  var n : Int = height
  var m, i, k : Int = 0

  for(i <- 0 until n; k = n/2){
    k - 1
    if(i+i == n) {
      m = k
      m = m - 1
    }
    for(j <- 1 to k.abs) {
      diamond = diamond + " "
    }
    for(j <- 1 to 2*scala.math.min(i, n-i-1)+1) {
      diamond = diamond + "#"
    }
    print("\n")
  }
  diamond
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/jO8h1IYtSPyJ5z7owNcexg).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering if I could return a string type instead of the iterator string. Sorry, my question might sound silly

Comment: I figured I could just use .mkString to convert a iterator string to string type. Thank you again

Comment: I'm sorry. I seem to have problem returning the iterator string as string type. result.mkString is not working.

Comment: Try `result.mkString("\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build half and then attach the reverse.

```
def diamond(height:Int):List[String] = {
  def build(space:Int, star:Int, acc:List[String]):List[String] =
    if (space < 0) acc.reverse
    else build(space-1, star+2, " "*space+"*"*star :: acc)

  val top = build(height/2 + height%2 - 1, 1, Nil)
  if (height % 2 > 0) top ++ top.reverse.tail
  else                top ++ top.reverse
}

diamond(4).foreach(println)
diamond(7).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Those are a lot of reversals on a linked list, what about this? :) https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/rBrlCNyqQluGcELFsNxpPg/9

Comment: @stefanobaghino; Good point and nice fix. I did notice, however, that your `diamond(7)` has 8 rows of output.

Comment: Whoops, should be fixed now: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/rBrlCNyqQluGcELFsNxpPg/14

Comment: Or rather https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/rBrlCNyqQluGcELFsNxpPg/15 (uses a constant `tail` instead of a linear `init`)

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `tabulate`:

```
def diamond(n: Int) = {
  val h = (n+1)/2
  def row(i: Int) = " " * (h - i) + "#" * (i * 2 - 1)

  List.tabulate(n/2)(i => row(i + 1)) ++ List.tabulate(h)(i => row(h - i))
}
```

This will show the first 7 diamonds:

```
(1 to 7).foreach { n =>
  println(s"---$n---")
  println(diamond(n).mkString("\n"))
}
```